# Связанные таблицы в mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы, связанные след. образом:

```
1. 1_table
          id
          name
2. 2_table
          f_id
```

Как я думаю понятно, FOREIGN KEY (f_id) REFERENCES 1_table(id)

Мне нужно вытащить name-ы по f_d через таблицу 2_table

к примеру. получить все name из 1_table, где id=3 (но обращаться нужно к 2_table к 1_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос

```
SELECT name
  FROM 1_table first INNER JOIN 2_table second ON first.id=second.f_id
  WHERE second.f_id = ?
```